# How to fill in the gap between a range of numbers?

Tags: sql, postgresql, range, data-cleaning

I have a database with number ranges entered using hyphens for example 1-10, 50-100, 34-38. 
How would I fill in the blanks where the hyphen is and create the whole numbers in between?

I need this:

> 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10

From this:

> 1-10

Comment: You are looking for `generate_series()`

Comment: which DBMS do you use?

Answer (score 2):

smth like:

```
t=# with s(v) as (values('2-13'))
select generate_series(split_part(v,'-',1)::int,split_part(v,'-',2)::int) r from s;
 r
----
  2
  3
  4
  5
  6
  7
  8
  9
 10
 11
 12
 13
(12 rows)
```

Comment: I receive this error with this solution:       ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: ""

********** Error **********

ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: ""
SQL state: 22P02

Comment: Yes. It is probably an issue with my table though.